# How to install modern PHP packages?

Tags: php

How do I install modern PHP packages? I haven't used PHP for 5 years so everything seems new.

In particular I'm trying to install `https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk`. I downloaded the code, but when I try to

```
require_once 'Pheanstalk/Pheanstalk.php'
```

I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Pheanstalk\PheanstalkInterface' not found
in /web/Pheanstalk/Pheanstalk.php
```

I found I should use `use`. When I try `use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk` I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk' not found in /web/test.php on line 5
```

Can't I just download and use PHP code anymore like back in the day? How do I get these modern packages working? Packages seem to mention `composer`. Should I use that? Can't I just download code and use it? I don't want to depend on `composer` or any other package manager. I just want to run code.

Comment: Read the error message.  Listen to what it is telling you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did read it. The class is there. Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk.php is a file with Pheanstalk class. It appears I need to do some extra work to make these classes available via `composer` or some new modern magic.

Comment: Where is the required `PheanstalkInterface`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have no idea. There is file Pheanstalk\PheanstalkInterface.php, which doesn't get loaded for some reason...

Comment: All the files from `https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/tree/master/src` are in `/web/Pheanstalk`.

Comment: Composer's package management is not required at all. What you need is an autoloader, such as: https://gist.github.com/mageekguy/8300961 or if not you need to manually `include` every single one of the files in that folder (and subfolders). Autoloading means you can break down your classes and interfaces into seperate files like this for better organisation, without 50 lines of includes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern way of installing packages is to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

It might seem scary at first, but it isn't such a big deal.

You should also be able to download and use the package yourself, if the creator made that possible, it should be explained in the documentation however.

There might be no "easy" way to install your package without composer if the package creator intended it that way. For this package in particular, the only instructions are for Composer, so it's safe to assume that it's the easiest way to install it.

Of course it's possible to use his code directly, but you'll need to know what you're doing and understand namespaces.

Comment: Thanks Dany. The documentation is poor and assumes I know modern packages already. It says "Hopefully you are using composer", which I am not. I'll need to try to learn it. :(

Comment: I agree, a lot of new packages have 'elitist' developers, they want you to use the proper tools, but they force it upon you like in this case.

Comment: @lxndr standards !== popular. There isn't a standards body voting on rules that say you must use composer. Composer is just popular. Next week a different package manager could come around and be the new *it*.

Comment: @lxndr I didn't say it Composer wasn't good, I use it myself obviously, I don't think it should be "forced" upon people though. It can be confusing for new developers.

Comment: OP just unfortunately picked a php package that requires the use of a package manager to load classes (or really some sort of autoloader for classes would work) and has poor documentation to say that.

Comment: Hi I got Pheanstalk working my friendos. :)))))))))) via composer